# App content going off bottom of display bc of TabWidget?

Tags: android, compatibility, tabwidget

I'm creating an app that contains a TabWidget at the top. Everything looks fine, except on smaller screen sizes, the content off the tab 'disappears' off the bottom of the screen. I've looked around for a solution, used only dp/sp to help the layout scale properly.. but nothing will work.

I imagine the problem is the tabwidget, since it doesn't seem to scale to new screen sizes. I don't know how to ensure my tabcontent is displayed on all screens? My tab activity's XML is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:typeface="monospace" 
    android:background="@drawable/target"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView
            android:text="Convert from:"
            android:id="@+id/convertFrom"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:typeface="monospace" 
            android:textSize="16dp"/>


           <EditText
               android:inputType="numberDecimal"           
               android:id="@+id/numberInput"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="16dp"
               android:layout_below="@id/convertFrom"/>

            <Spinner 
                android:id="@+id/spinner_one" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/numberInput"></Spinner>

            <TextView
            android:text="Convert to:"
            android:typeface="monospace" 
            android:id="@+id/text_to"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/spinner_one"/>

            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_two"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_to"></Spinner>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:layout_below="@id/spinner_two"/>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thisequals"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/button"
            android:maxLines="1"
            layout_alignParentRight="true"
            layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer"
            android:textColor="#FF4400"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:typeface="sans" 
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_below="@id/thisequals"/>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ofthis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/answer"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is main.xml (if needed) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

here is a picture of the problem (same thing should show on both screens.. one HVGA and QVGA)

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15931335/appproblem.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems there's not enough space for this layout just because of small screen size. That's a normal situation when you deal with small-screen devices. You can put this layout inside a scroll view or make it smaller to fit the smalles screen. I think you can consider 320x240 ldpi screen as the smallest one.

Comment: ok I understand.. I really wanted to keep it all on one screen, so I'm hesitant to use a scrollView. However, if I design the app to fully fit on the smallest screen, will it then only take up part of a larger screen? Is there a way to make it stretch to fit all screens in the same way?

Comment: You can design your app to look differently on different screens. I'm not sure there's way to support all the screens so that the layout will look good on all screens. Sometimes it's possible and sometimes it's not. In your case I would make layout more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try replacing your LinearLayout attributes in main.xml with this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight="1.0">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```